# Creating global webserver without port forwarding

Tags: esp8266, c++, web-server

I'm setting up a "Smart House" project with Arduino+Esp01F(Serial Communication).
But I want to make it global server. For it I use WiFiEsp library. But for it I must Get any port (neither 80 nor 443), then make port forwarding on router. But there are no port forwarding in my router. I think how can I do it? 
Code:

```cpp
#include "WiFiEsp.h"

// Emulate Serial1 on pins 6/7 if not present
#ifndef HAVE_HWSERIAL1
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
SoftwareSerial Serial1(6, 7); // RX, TX
#endif
 String response = "";
char ssid[] = "Nazim";            // your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = "eminmamedov1";         // your network password
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;     // the Wifi radio's status
int reqCount = 0;                // number of requests received

WiFiEspServer server(5000);

 WiFiEspClient client;


void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
  // initialize serial for ESP module
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  // initialize ESP module
  WiFi.init(&Serial1);

  // check for the presence of the shield
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
    // don't continue
    while (true);
  }

  // attempt to connect to WiFi network
  while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  }

  Serial.println("You're connected to the network");
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

WiFi.config(IPAddress(192,168,0,165));
  // start the web server on port 80
  server.begin();

}

void loop() {
   WiFiEspClient client = server.available();
   if(client){
    String res = "";
     Serial.println("New client");
      while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();

        res+=c;

        if (c == '\n') {
          Serial.println("Sending response");
           client.print(
            "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
            "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
            "Connection: close\r\n"  // the connection will be closed after completion of the response
               "\r\n");
               if(res.indexOf("on?") >=0){
               int s = res.indexOf("on?")+7;
               int f = s+2;
               String ss = res.substring(s,f);
                  int i = ss.toInt();
                 if(i != 6 && i != 7&& (i>=2)&&(i<=13)){

                  pinMode(i,OUTPUT);
                  digitalWrite(i,HIGH);
                  bool s = digitalRead(i);
                  String state = s ? "OFF\r\n" : "ON\r\n";
                  client.println(state);
                 }else{
                  client.println("ERROR\r\n");
                 }
               }else if(res.indexOf("off?") >=0){
                 int s = res.indexOf("off?")+8;
               int f = s+2;
               String ss = res.substring(s,f);
                  int i = ss.toInt();
                 if(i != 6 && i != 7&& (i>=2)&&(i<=13)){

                  pinMode(i,OUTPUT);
                  digitalWrite(i,LOW);
                  bool s = digitalRead(i);
                  String state = s ? "OFF\r\n" : "ON\r\n";
                  client.println(state);
                 }else{
                  client.println("ERROR\r\n");
                 }
               }else if(res.indexOf("state?") >=0){
                 int s = res.indexOf("state?")+9;
               int f = s+2;
               String ss = res.substring(s,f);
                  int i = ss.toInt();
                 if(i != 6 && i != 7&& (i>=2)&&(i<=13)){

                  bool s = digitalRead(i);
                  String state = s ? "OFF\r\n" : "ON\r\n";
                  client.println(state);
               }
               }





                   client.stop();

      }
      }


   }






}
```

Comment: You can't. Get a better router.

Comment: The ESP does only provide the server. The traffic from and to that server has to be routed between your local network and the internet. That is, what a router is for. You need a better one

Comment: I heard there is the IP Cameras without port forwarding(it works without por). I thought that was p2p but No. How can I realize it in my ketch

Comment: use the DMZ setting in the router to expose your server to the internet

Comment: @TheGamerCoder You may be talking about UPnP which can configure port forwarding for you. Or there are cameras that communicate with a service on the internet so need no port forwarding (they connect outwards).  If your router supports UPnP (why it would support that and *not* port forwarding would be a mystery) then maybe you could do it with that.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461516/esp8266-upnp-port-forwarding-iot)

Comment: Incidentally, to do that you will have to give up the idea of using the AT command set and trying to get it working with an Arduino, and program the ESP8266 directly.

Comment: Can I use for it Esp01f adapter?

Comment: Only if you program it directly instead of using an Arduino as I said above.

Comment: Can I use UPnP Tiny library with WiFiEsp?

Comment: use web sockets and an always-on cloud server for 2-way non-ported real time communication.

Comment: What? How to use it? And Can I use it with WiFiEsp + TinyUPnP

Comment: What part of "Only if you program it directly instead of using an Arduino" don't you understand?

Comment: STOP. I understand. But how to use WEBSOCKETS and ALWAYS-ON CLOUD SERVER I didn't understand

Comment: @TheGamerCoder Use `@` followed by a username to direct your comments at a particular user.

Comment: I mean how to realize @dandavis said

Comment: typically, you need a VPS to run a websocker server on. there's some free VPS options, and a few hosted websocket server options, like pubnub and pusher.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks  for information, but how can  I add VPS to wifi sketch